# Infinite Image slider with pure CSS3

Tags: css

There are numerous example of sliders made by `CSS3`, but almost all of them needs click trigger to change the slide. I wonder if it is possible to make a auto-slider, which continuously and indefinitely change the slides.

For example, consider a structure as

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
       First DIV
    </div>
    <div class="child">
       Second DIV
    </div>
    <div class="child">
       Third DIV
    </div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

can we continueously scroll the `child` elements inside the `parent` frame?

Comment: You will get here what you want http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: @Mr.Alien absolutely marvelous! exactly what I was looking for. If you turn it into an answer, I can accept it. This can lead other people too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suggested, that I should answer instead of a comment so here it goes, you can refer to a source here - http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ which uses CSS3 animations to swap the images.

Though I would suggest you to use jQuery or JS instead of CSS3 animations due to cross browser support especially when it comes to IE.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for pure CSS3? Then this is what you are looking for:

[CSS3 image slider](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-image-slider-with-stylized-thumbnails)