# Pure css3 image slider

Tags: html, css

i need to make image slider using pure css3 and not using any jquery. i just tried this

```
    #content-slider {
    font-family: arial;
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px #c9c9c9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px #c9c9c9;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px #c9c9c9;
}

#content-inner {
    width:10000px;
    height: 480px;
}

.page {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    float: left;
}

.page-info {
    height: 90px;
    background-color: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.6);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    bottom: 103px;
    color: #dedede;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.page-info h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: #fafafa;
}

.page-text {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.button {
    float: left;
    background: #bababa;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.button:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #d4d4d4;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #d4d4d4;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #d4d4d4;
}

.button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #7a7a7a;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #7a7a7a;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #7a7a7a;
}

.button a {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

#content-inner-1:target #content-inner {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#content-inner-2:target #content-inner {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-left: -640px;
}

#content-inner-3:target #content-inner {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-left: -1280px;
}

#content-inner-4:target #content-inner {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-left: -1920px;
}

#content-inner-5:target #content-inner {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-left: -2560px;
}

#content-inner-6:target #content-inner {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-left: -3200px;
}
```

but it need to be click (please check my jsfiddle [this](http://jsfiddle.net/agungimannuel/xCbqY/)). I want to automatically slide from right to left like in [this](http://ragnarok2.lytogame.com/default.asp) site. Can somebody help me?

sorry for my bad English. Thanks.

Comment: Don't want to close your question as a possible duplicate as you've attempted to make a slider yourself, but if you want to check out pure CSS3 slider, than here you go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863967/infinite-image-slider-with-pure-css3/18864411#18864411

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, but it  didn't solved my problem. There are just two images and not sliding from right to left. i want to automatic sliding from right to left. Can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you combine [Infinite Image slider with pure CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863967/infinite-image-slider-with-pure-css3/18864411#18864411) (for the automatic delay/transition between multiple images) with this [How to create 'Slide-in gallery panels' with jQuery/CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932982/how-to-create-slide-in-gallery-panels-with-jquery-css3/21939282#21939282) (for the sliding part).

Tell me if you need more details.