# Is there any way I can change an div element in an outside div with css

Tags: html, css

I have this list

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>list el</li>
    <li>list el</li>
    <li>list el
       <ul>
          <li>inside</li>
          <li>inside2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  <img src="#">
  <h1>Some Title</h1>
</section
```

And I am using :focus to display the dropdown list on click, without using JS. Everything is ok for now. But I would like to,change the color of the entire section  when the dropdown list is active (through :focus).
Is there any way I could do that entirely with css? I am trying to use as little JS as possible (definetly no jQuery)

Comment: I saw this type of questions many times today, and having not an answer that wrap-up the results, so just use javascript...

Comment: Simply: no. You must use JS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, **without the slightest bit of JS**, using the Radio Hack. Basically, use a label as your "focused" element. This label should have its `for` attribute refer to an `input type="radio"` that is hierarchically above the elements that you want affected. Then just use the following css selector `#myradio:checked ~ #mysection{  }`.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939282/2306481

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to changing from using `:focus` to using `:target` then yes you can.

It is not clear from your question how you are implementing your drop-down behaviour, but this is a simple example, that should explain how you can approach it. *(only the third item has a drop down, but all three links should change the background colour)*.

The behaviour of `:target` is a little different to `:focus` however, so things that you need to be aware of are:

1. target will change the URL, creating a history point.
2. target will retain the "focus" even if the user clicks on a different element, the only time a target is lost is when another target is targeted.

```css
li ul {display: none;}

#dd1:target { background: gold; }
#dd2:target { background: green; }
#dd3:target { background: red; }

#dd3:target .dd3 {display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="dd1">
<div id="dd2">
<div id="dd3">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#dd1">list el</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dd2">list el</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dd3">list el</a>
        <ul class="dd3">
          <li>inside</li>
          <li>inside2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the thing is, one of the things I need to do is, when the user clicks on the <section>, or anywhere else, the dropdown must close as well. So the #2 that you mentioned is kind of a big deal for me. But thanks! That's really good to know.