# How to change the images using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I don't know whether this question make sense . But i have this doubt .. please clear my doubt

For assumption , i have 5 images ,Is this possible to change 5 images one by one [like slider] using HTML  and CSS styles without using jquery and javascript

Comment: What do you mean by *[like slider]*

Comment: This is pretty much for only css and html. Why can't you use JS?

Comment: @Martin Just now i started HTML and CSS not yet touched JS so only

Comment: @Mr.Alien Image should change automatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18864411/1542290 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. A quick google search took me to this working example with code:

[CSS Slider](http://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf)