# Slideshow with content animated in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, css-animations

I have a slideshow with 3 images. For each of the image I have need to add some content on top of the image, and the text need to move from right to left, and gone in 3 secs. Then it will slide to the 2nd image, and again, I have to display the content from right to left again, this time with a background box at the back of the text.

How can I do this kind of animation in css? Moreover, this slider need to be compatible for all browsers.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to give a little more specific information. Do you have an example, perhaps, that you've seen somewhere else? For example, do you just want a simple slider? -- or are you saying you want the pieces to slide in from different angles in addition to the slider?

Comment: You can use jquery image slider library. just search for it, you find many...

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18864411/1542290)?

Comment: @HunterRose I dont have sample for it. It's just like normal slider, but normally we only have include image on it. In this case, they want the image as the background, and then once the image is shown, a text will be displayed from left to right after a sec. Then after 3 secs, then image will change to the 2nd image and another content will be shown again. That's roughly the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do that kind of animation with CSS, but you would have to use javascript to trigger the animations. The method you are talking about would not work for all browsers. If you can use jQuery for your projects, then you can use the animate feature. Plus it would be compatible for essentially all browsers that people use.

For the CSS approach, you would use the `animation` property, like this

```
@keyframes {
    from { color: #fff; } to { color: #000; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes {
    from { color: #fff; } to { color: #000; }
}
.myanimatedclass{
    animation: myanimation 2s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation: myanimation 2s ease-in;
}
```

For the jQuery approach, look up jQuery's animate feature. You will find all that you need.
https://api.jquery.com/animate/