# Three images changing with keyframe animation css3

Tags: image, css, animation, keyframe

I am new to CSS3 keyframe animations and I'm trying to create animation with three images, where each image would stay for 2 seconds, then change to 2nd image, which would stay 2 seconds as well and then change to the last 3rd image, which would also stay 2 seconds. This animation would then loop back to the first image...second...third...etc.

I have created the following Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klarita/yyRQ8/
I know the stylesheet is a mess at the moment as I can't work it out, Could anyone advice please.

I will need to use the same technique for 6 images later on, just need to understand how it all works.

HTML:

```
<div id="crossfade">
   <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5145/5576437826_940f2db110.jpg" alt="Image 1">
   <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3611/3463265789_586ce40aef.jpg" alt="Image 2">
   <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2657/5739934564_357f849b58_z.jpg" alt="Image 3">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#crossfade > img { 
    width: 185px;
    height: 185px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 10s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 10s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 10s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 10s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 10s linear infinite 0s; 
}

#crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}

#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    50% { opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    50% { opacity: 0;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    50% { opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    50% { opacity: 0;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    50% { opacity: 0;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Comment: Instead of re inventing the wheel, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18863967/1542290

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mr.Alien…I have actually started of this tutorial (http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/), but
my problem is that I don't understand how to make it working for three (and later six) images instead. 
I can't work out how to count the Opacity and the Percentage for the keyframes and also the animation-delay.